# Night vision camera

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera

I'm looking for a nightvision camera. It's meant to be relatively cheap (under $70). I want to use it with a device similar to the Raspberry Pi 4B, but the connector does not matter. Currently, I've got this one: [NV camera](https://thepihut.com/products/raspberry-pi-night-vision-camera), but there is a one-second-ish lag and the night vision feature is turned on all day, which ruins the image so that it's no longer usable. Also, the camera must have autofocus. Do you have any recommendations?